# Routing Error , No route matches [GET] "/categorys/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The name of the table is "category", controller is "categories". I have added `resources :categories` in routes file.

Why is it showing `"Routing Error/ No route matches [GET] /categorys/new"`? The following is the code in controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def create
    @category = category.build(category_params)

    if @category.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like you have a typo and used `categorys` instead of `categories` somewhere (maybe in the views?)

Comment: Or in browser address?

Answer (score 2):

The route you've defined is named `categories`, but the URL in the error is `categorys` -- that shouldn't have come from a URL helper, but maybe you built the URL manually? Either way, it doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `resources :categories` would produce `GET /categories/new` endpoint (along with others), but not `GET /categorys/new`. See [Rails routing guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) for more info.